# Extract by Expression w/ two conditions stopping when first condition is met in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extract, conditional, qgis-expression

I have an output from ST-DBSCAN with the attribute "CLUSTER_SIZE". I'd like to extract only attributes belonging to clusters of size >= 10. If this condition cannot be met, then extract attributes with clusters of size >= 7. If this condition cannot be met, NULL can be returned.

I am working with the following code:

```
CASE
WHEN "CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 10 THEN TRUE
WHEN "CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 7 THEN TRUE
END
```

Since layers with CLUSTER_SIZE >= 10 will always also have CLUSTER_SIZE >= 7, the algorithm needs to stop if the first condition is already met. According to QGIS documentation for CASE, this code would provide exactly that:

> CASE is used to evaluate a series of conditions and return a result
> for the first condition met. The conditions are evaluated
> sequentially, and if a condition is true, the evaluation stops, and
> the corresponding result is returned.

Yet outputs for layers with CLUSTER_SIZE >= 10 are instead filtered by CLUSTER_SIZE >= 7. It seems CASE is not stopping at the first condition.

I have also tried:

```
CASE
    WHEN "CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 10 THEN TRUE
    ELSE "CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 7
END
```

and

```
if("CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 10, TRUE, if( "CLUSTER_SIZE" >= 7, TRUE, FALSE))
```

But the problem persists. How can I write a conditional code for QGIS' "Extract by Expression" tool that returns if the first condition is met and continues only if it's not?

For clarification, the outputs I need are:

- Layers **only** with clusters >= 10 if they have clusters of at least this size
- Layers **only** with clusters >= 7 if they do not have any clusters bigger than 10

I am basically loosening my filter in case I have layers with clusters smaller than 10, but this is to be done as an exception only.

Comment: Any cluster with size >= 10 also meets your second condiction... so why have the first condition anyway?

Comment: @Erik if a layer has cluster sizes >= 7 and also >= 10, I want only clusters of size >= 10 to be extracted. Clusters of size 7, 8, 9 should only be extracted if the layer does not have clusters of size >= 10. I have edited my question so that it is hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check, whether you cluster size is equal to or exceeds 10, before selecting features. You can use [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=maximum#maximum) for this task.

```
if(maximum("CLUSTER_SIZE")>=10,"CLUSTER_SIZE">=10,"CLUSTER_SIZE">=7)
```

does, what you're looking for. `maximum("CLUSTER_SIZE")>=10` checks, whether your cluster sizes meet or exceed 10. If that is true, all clusters with a size 10+ are selected. Otherwise all clusters with 7+ features are selected.